# Is it possible to have a table with a width of 100% but stop at 1920px? Due to monitor size?

Tags: html, css

Was curious because I like to design images to be adjusted for any screen and then set them as cell backgrounds with a width of 100% so that when people adjust the window size or monitor size is different. The image will get eaten by the window but the logo in the cell will still hover over the image in the desired position.

It works great I think. I have the exact desired effect I want with one flaw.
Because 4k is a thing now and monitor resolutions are soon to increase I'm going to have to spend more time making sure the header image will be around 4000px wide just to fit their screens.

My question is. In a table with width="100%" is there a way to change it to width = 100% but the window size goes over say 1920px the size of one of my images then the 100% stops?

I ask because the project I'm working I have the logo floating over the header image but is aligned in the cell to the left so whenever you drag the left of the window out it stays but the image get's eaten. You can see it here http://www.theroyaloaknonington.co.uk/beta/

Sadly on a monitor with a resolution with a width wider than 1920 the logo still flows off the image on to the grey zone because the image is only 1920px wide. Was wondering what would be the best way to stop this?

Check the live example link a few paragraphs up. And if your monitor doesn't exceed 1920 then it will look fine but if you drag the left side of the window to make the size smaller you will see the logo move. And sadly when it's extended wider than 1920 the logo goes on. I want it to be free but stop at the end of the image.

Comment: The `max-width` attribute does exactly this.

Comment: Table based designs are long gone, don't use them. This can be achieved easily with DIV based design and javascript. Stop using tables and start using DIVs if you want best results.

Comment: Not a helpful comment really is it altafhussain? I mean sure I could scrap the web page and restart using DIV tags. Or I could build this very simple website using a very simple method which still works? I appreciate it would be better using a DIV tag but if you really wish to answer the question then how about telling me how to achieve the effect using DIV tags rather than just telling me to use DIV tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is, and it is very simple:

```
table {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1920px;
}
```

For more complex requirements, then you would need to start looking at `@media` queries, where you can specify the range of screen sizes that individual styles apply to.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `max-width: 1920px;` to prevent an element from extending beyond that width.

There is probably a nicer way to do this with media queries, perhaps establishing if the device width is over 1920px and then setting the table width to 1920 explicitly.

EDIT: With media queries you could use this:

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 1920px) {
    table { 
        width: 1920px;
    }
}
```

It's worth noting that min-width of 1920 resolution may be a little smaller than 1920, probably 1880 or something along those lines.

Answer (score 3):

```
table {
    max-width: 1920px;
}
```

Use [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

For ie use https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond

Answer (score 3):

```
max-width: 1920px;
```

Should do it. And just have the normal width 100%

Answer (score 1):

Never use tables for layouts, use DIV (or HEADER element) and CSS.

For the rest you should read about [responsive design](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_Web_Design) and [CSS media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)